# Нужно вытащить инфу из PNG

Tags: utf-8, шифрование, unicode, hex, стеганография

Нужно вытащить стороннюю информацию из картинки.

Подсказки:
Метод шифрования связан с кибер-безобасностью.
Сама картинка просто взята из интернета, неизвестно что в ней могут быть за артефакты.
В картинке или **Ссылка** или **Другая картинка** или **Текст**

Создатель говорит о ней так:

1 - "я инфо безник"

2 - "её я сделал в соло и она очень лёгкая, просто надо знать, что искать и как искать"

[image: Изображение со скрытой информацией]

Comment: Например, можно просто записать свою информацию по одному биту в каждый из 3-х цветов каждого пикселя. Только надо позаботится об уникальной последовательности для кодирования признака ее конца

Comment: @avp подозреваю что всё проще и информация там просто в чанке с комментарием.

Comment: [Что-то](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z6YoY.png) там есть, но разгадывать лень.

Comment: По **b1,rgb,lsb,xy** выдаёт многострочку `\ntadluudcl\ndqsushhud\nrmtzamjrgqgb\nowibnivvur\nskbynqx\nfub\nfnsqczqlp\neekr\nzukgr\niqm\niqghhmk\npswzfztfeor\nlhdososrra\nhdajkwyjc\npml\nmcunotfpoog\naenn\nqvfjdebnx\nesdaeenjpp\nzdcygkocgdwa\nhyizstsq\nsbuecriqv\nkov\nkglbfridcq\nhaqfeijqf\nzqusqewebg\naevxiodbztm\njvovealysgs`, но что с ней дальше делать не понятно.

Comment: Дальше видимо Цезарь или четыре квадрата

Comment: там не должно быть никакого шифра по типу цезаря или квадрата

Comment: А что там должно быть?

Comment: Прямой ответ, скорее всего ссылка на чтото.
Я многострочку твою через все что мог перегнал, 0 результатов.
Все слова кстати начинаются на одну букву, просто заметил, вдруг это важно...

Comment: По стандартным средствам для стеганограмм ничего интересного не выдаёт кроме этой строки, мета пустая. Либо попробовать квадраты как-то перетасовать, либо чанки, но это слишком сложно звучит.

Comment: Вроде получилось: `there is no quest with a portal it's just an excuse`

Comment: Вау, да, это то что там было спрятано. А в чем загадка была? 
обидно еще то что он спрятал какую-то хрень ради которой я столько человека мучал

Comment: Просто повезло на [этот сайт](https://planetcalc.com/9345/) попасть, подход тот же — LSB. Но, почему то `zsteg` выдал **28** строк, а сайт **62**, среди которых искомое сообщение, строки повторяются частично. Вопрос почему такая разница открытый. Изначально думал, что дело в чанках, по `pngcheck` их 3, разделены по 8192, что логично, т.к. это лимит для PNG. Но если файл пересохранить в PS, будет один чанк на 5552, а результаты для `zsteg` и сайта не поменяются. Что-то сайт ещё дополнительно делает.

Comment: К слову, [ещё один сайт](https://stylesuxx.github.io/steganography/) тоже полное сообщение выдаёт, почему `zsteg` до конца не отработал не понятно.

Comment: как тут выбрать ответ на вопрос, или тут все само произойдет. увидел ) спасибо за ответ на вопрос

Comment: Да не, это не ответ, это комментарии. Попозже может оформлю в ответ. Ну и кросс-линк на [issue на GH](https://github.com/zed-0xff/zsteg/issues/35) оставлю пока.

Answer (score 1):

Итак, дошли руки написать полноценный ответ.

Есть множество ресурсов на тему. Стоит отметить [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/codes/) где публикуются различные задания и их разгадывают. Также на GH есть репозитории посвящённые CTF, в том числе по PNG. (CTF — Capture The Flag).

А что дальше? А дальше у нас есть множество ресурсов по [стеганография](/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%84%d0%b8%d1%8f), например [этот](https://fareedfauzi.gitbook.io/ctf-playbook/steganography) и [этот](https://stegonline.georgeom.net/checklist), или [этот](https://book.hacktricks.xyz/crypto-and-stego/stego-tricks). Ресурсы могут быть в будущем недоступны, поэтому ответим на главный вопрос:

> просто надо знать, что искать и как искать

Чтож, как искать — уже сложилась традиция и инструменты. Если рассматривать простые CTF, они так или иначе уповают на стандартные инструменты. Средние — это комбинация с хитростями, сложные — это что-то, что вы не найдёте в интернете, или искать будет очень сложно.
Остановимся на простых-средних. Они, опять же, очень доступным языком описаны даже на [пикабу](https://pikabu.ru/story/steganografiya_razbor_prosteyshey_tulzyi_dlya_skryitiya_informatsii_v_kartinke_7577381).

Желательно иметь под рукой linux или WSL.

1. Пробуем команду `file`, она покажет что из себя представляет изображение. Файл может именоваться **jpeg**, а по сути быть PNG. Если разрешение не совпадает, то это уже подозрительно, надо копать! К слову, в Forensic практике, откуда у меня большая часть опыта, файлы проверяют на сигнатуры (signatures), т.е. начало файла. Если оно не совпадает с разрешением, это дико подозрительно. Windows отобразит PNG как PNG, даже если его назвать ***.jpg, так устроена система, но важно знать с каким файлом имеем дело. Для linux и вовсе разрешения не важны, это скорее удобство, гораздо важнее разрешения на файл, и, в частности, исполняемый он или нет.
2. Проверили файл, отлично, убедились, что это PNG.
   Что дальше? Метаданные. Их обязательно стоит проверить. Там могут быть лёгкие флаги. Для этого используем:

   - `exiftool`
   - `exiv2`

   Оба хороши. Первый выдаст:

   ```
   Warning : [minor] Text/EXIF chunk(s) found after PNG IDAT (may be ignored by some readers)
   ```

   Наверное, единственное к чему стоит придраться. Но, если поискать по этой ошибке, создатели говорят, что стоит использовать другие инструменты, а другие (exiv2) не выдают ничего более интересного, и если в ручную хексом посмотреть, там нет ничего интересного, поехали далее.
3. Далее я использовал `xxd`, по нему ничего интересного, останавливаться не буду.
4. `strings` — очень классная команда, позволяет найти завуалированные сообщения. Для неё необходимо поставить: `apt-get install binutils`. В нашем случае видим чанки и ничего интересного.
5. `binwalk` — мощнейший инструмент для CTF. Не важно, склеили ли вы файл банальной командой, которая склеивает jpg и rar (любой другой архив), или как-то хитрее, в большинстве случаев данная команда покажет склейку. Всё зависит от хтрости, верить ей полноценно не стоит, может и не показать. А может показать false positive:

   ```
   DECIMAL       HEXADECIMAL     DESCRIPTION
   --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   0             0x0             PNG image, 1015 x 393, 8-bit/color RGBA, non-interlaced
   17481         0x4449          TIFF image data, big-endian, offset of first image directory: 8
   ```

   Видим TIFF, но по размеру понятно, что там ничего нет. Можно сделать экстракцию через `binwalk --dd='.*' 3.png`, но интересного там ничего нет. Также команда поддерживает deflate и прочее сжатие, но, опять же, мимо. Может быть не мимо для других CTF.
6. `foremost` тоже дико крутая штука, как binwalk, но мимо.
7. `pngcheck` — раз уж мы имеем дело с PNG, абсолютно нужная штука. Что выдаст `pngcheck -c -v -t 3.png`:

   ```
   File: 3.png (17511 bytes)
     chunk IHDR at offset 0x0000c, length 13
       1015 x 393 image, 32-bit RGB+alpha, non-interlaced
     chunk sRGB at offset 0x00025, length 1
       rendering intent = perceptual
     chunk IDAT at offset 0x00032, length 8192
       zlib: deflated, 32K window, fast compression
     chunk IDAT at offset 0x0203e, length 8192
     chunk IDAT at offset 0x0404a, length 1007
     chunk eXIf at offset 0x04445, length 14: EXIF metadata, big-endian (MM) format
     chunk IEND at offset 0x0445f, length 0
   No errors detected in 3.png (7 chunks, 98.9% compression).
   ```

   Опять же, мало чего полезного.
   Имеем стандартный PNG, чанки по 8192, что является лимитом для PNG и вполне логично. Если бы чанки были меньше — вот это было бы подозрительно. Но тут всё . Смущает только то, что если в Photoshop сохранить файл, то изображение помещается в один чанк, без потери в качестве и изначальном сообщении, значит что-то там спрятано!
8. Иструментов далее куча! Это и `stegseek`, `steghide`, `stegsolve` и много-много других.
   Остановимся на `zsteg`.
   И тут всё интересно. Библиотека на ruby смотрит MSB и LSB, гуглите :)
   Если вкратце, LSB — least significant bit, в отличие от MSB слабо меняет изображение и идеально подходит для стеганографии. Что это значит? Это значит, что информация помещается попиксельно с минимальными изменениями, где зелёный продолжает быть зелёным, для глазу непринциписально, смотри комментарий @avp. Тут можно много навыдумывать, но есть и инструменты, такие как `zsteg`. Помимо него полезно попробовать `Stegsolve.jar`, но тут всё идёт автоматически. И, вот проблема, библиотека выдала многострочную **string**, но в ней не было искомой информации. Она нашлась по тем же алгоритмам в онлайн инструментах: [ [1](https://planetcalc.com/9345/) | [2](https://stylesuxx.github.io/steganography/) ]. Почему? Будем разбираться в [issue на GH](https://github.com/zed-0xff/zsteg/issues/35).

   Тут ответ:

   > there is no quest with a portal it's just an excuse
9. Если ничего не нашлось (а уже нашлось), стоит смотреть в более [экзотические методы](https://habr.com/ru/companies/vdsina/articles/518292/), например, как по ссылке, скрытие информации в области, которая не будет рендериться при открытии. Инструменты ничего не покажут, глаз увидит, если знать. Всё что нужно — расширить область рендеринга в `IHDR`, при этом соблюсти CRC. Как написано в статье, если не получается посчитать его, берите другой файл с схожим разрешением. На самом деле можно поменять размерность и получить искомый CRC через `pngcheck`, это довольно просто.
   Но, здесь ничего не скрыто.
10. Если рассматривать продвинутый уровень CTF, там может быть что угодно! Всё выше описанное, возможно надо будет отредактировать файл и переместить квадраты, возможно собрать сообщение из нескольких LSB, возможно смотреть на размер чанков, или убирать их, чтобы увидеть сообщение, тут раздолье для шифропанков. Оставим сложные задачи для соревновательного формата и не будем раскрывать все секреты :)